# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner: run test method multiple times with different input data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, junit4

I'm developing tests for Spring application. I have several tests that i want to run multiple times for different data.

I can't use JUnit's @Parameters because test class must be run with Parameterized.class to make this work, while i have to run test classes with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class that sets up mock Spring context.
Unfortunately, it seems that [this runner doesn't support processing of the @Parameters annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html). I also took a look at TestContextBootstrapper and TextExecutionListener, but it seems that it can't help me either.

Is there a way to run test of the Spring application multiple times for different input data?

I need something similar to TestNG's `@Test(dataProvider=) @DataProvider` couple or `@Factory(dataProvider = ) @DataProvider` couple.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you can depend on JUnit 4.12, you can use `Parameterized` with `@UseParametersRunnerFactory`

First, create a class that implements `ParameterizedRunnerFactory`, returning an instance of the `Runner` that you want to run the tests:

```
public class SpringJUnit4ClassRunnerFactory
    implements ParameterizedRunnerFactory {
  @Override
  public Runner createRunnerForTestWithParameters(final TestWithParameters test)
         throws InitializationError {
     return new SpringJUnit4ClassRunner(testClass.getJavaClass()) {
       @Override
       protected Object createTest() throws Exception {
         Object[] args = test.getParameters().toArray();
         Object testInstance = test.getTestClass().getOnlyConstructor()
             .newInstance(args);

         // copied from SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest():
         getTestContextManager().prepareTestInstance(testInstance);
         return testInstance;
       }
     };
  }
}
```

Then you can annotate your test class with `@UseParametersRunnerFactory`:

```
@UseParametersRunnerFactory
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FooTesdt {
}
```

See [the Parameterized Javadoc](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) for details.

Comment: So i need to run my test class with `Parameterized` runner, specify factory with `@UseParametersRunnerFactory`, this factory must return a subclass of SpringJUnit4Runner (extended with constructor that accepts `TestWithParameters`) and `getParameters()` method of `TestWithParameters` must return List of arguments that will be passed to constructor of my test class?

Answer (score -2):

Found a bit simpler solution [here](http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1077/runwith-junit4-with-both-springjunit4classrunner-and-parameterized/).

Will post which of solutions did worked for me.